# 360/Panoramas degrees rotating view of a room by jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, panoramas

see this first https://www.commonfloor.com/live-in-tour#

here people can see full room picture just clicking on navigation button and when page load first then also image is moving slowly to show the inside.

i search google with keyword jquery plugin 360 view then found many. i explore those links.....here are few

```
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Cyclotron-Panorama-Image-Display-Plugin/
http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel#requirements
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Virtual-Tour-Simple-Panorama-Viewer-Plugin/demos/
http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/jqueryphotonav/
http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/build-360-view-image-slider-javascript-3122883
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/panorama_viewer_demo.html#
http://www.matchmaster.com.au/applications/3d/index.html
https://pannellum.org/  //best one
https://code.google.com/p/jspanoviewer/
```

i saw no plugin is showing to navigate up and down clicking on button. all plug in allow to navigate left to right. so if any plug in exist which allow us to view images like the link i posted then please share with me. i am looking for free jquery plugin.

another question is how jquery plug in can show a full room inside. i guess they are working with multiple images. but in what order i need to place the multiple images so it can show right view of a room or any images. so please tell me briefly how this kind of plugin is working. thanks

Comment: i found no comments or answers :(

Comment: this website is using http://krpano.com/ (panaroma viewer)

Comment: or you can check out http://threejs.org